# Python - getting source code with socket

Tags: python, sockets

I wanna send http get request and receive source code from webpage, this has to be done through sockets. I set buffer size to 4096, but my script download only small part from the page

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
sock.connect ( ( "edition.cnn.com", 80 ) )

host = socket.gethostbyname("edition.cnn.com")
sock.sendall('GET http://edition.cnn.com/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n'\
    + 'User-Agent: agent123\r\n'\
    + 'Host: '+host+'\r\n'\
    + '\r\n')

print sock.recv(4096)
sock.close()
```

After I run this code data I get are

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: nginx

Date: Wed, 01 Jan 2014 18:31:25 GMT

Content-Type: text/html

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Connection: keep-alive

Set-Cookie: CG=GR:44:Réthimnon; path=/

Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Jan 2014 18:31:22 GMT

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Cache-Control: max-age=60, private

Expires: Wed, 01 Jan 2014 18:32:25 GMT



ac2a


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>CNN.com International - Breaking, World, Business, Sports, Entertainment and Video News</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="2014-01-01T18:28:34Z"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800;url=http://edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive"/>
<meta name="description" content="CNN.com International delivers breaking news from across the globe and information on the latest top stories, business, sports and entertainment headlines. Follow the news as it happens through: special reports, videos, audio, photo galleries plus interactive maps and timelines."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="CNN, CNN news, CNN International, CNN International news, CNN Edition, Edition news, news, news online, breaking news, U.S. news, world news, global news, weather, business, CNN Money, sports, politics, law, technology, entertainment, education,
```

Which isn't even first 13 rows from source code... view-source:http://edition.cnn.com/index.html

---

And another problem, when I try address google.com like a host

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
sock.connect ( ( "google.com", 80 ) )

host = socket.gethostbyname("google.com")
sock.sendall('GET http://google.com/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n'\
    + 'User-Agent: agent123\r\n'\
    + 'Host: '+host+'\r\n'\
    + '\r\n')
print sock.recv(4096)
sock.close()
```

I get this response

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Location: http://www.google.com/index.html

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Date: Wed, 01 Jan 2014 18:38:57 GMT

Expires: Fri, 31 Jan 2014 18:38:57 GMT

Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000

Server: gws

Content-Length: 229

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic



<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/index.html">here</A>.

</BODY></HTML>
```

which says that page is moved to the same address like i wanted download...

Comment: `GET http://google.com/index.html HTTP/1.1`, ie `google.com` redirects to `www.google.com`, not at all the same address.

Comment: Why don't you use an [HTTP client](http://docs.python-requests.org/)?

Comment: Because I have to communicate through sockets

Comment: @user3149628: Every HTTP client library does that. Do you mean you have to write code using sockets directly yourself?

Comment: oh, really? so i can use urllib to process it? in the description of project I have: must use the HTTP GET request to fetch StartURL, must communicate with an HTTP server through sockets.

Answer (score 3):

`sock.recv(4096)` will read **up to** 4096 bytes; it depends on how much data has already arrived how much can actually be returned by the call. There is no guarantee that 4096 bytes will actually be available for reading in one go.

You'll have to *continue* to read from the socket until all data is received:

```
data = ''
chunk = sock.recv(4096)
while chunk:
    data += chunk
    if len(data) >= 4096:
        break
    chunk = sock.recv(4096)
```

Your request to `http://google.com/index.html` redirects to `www.google.com`, a **different** hostname. Adjust your request accordingly.

If you wanted to implement a full-on HTTP client, you'd have to parse the status line, process the `301` redirect response by parsing out the `Location:` header, and making a new connection to request the new URL given to you.

Answer (score 0):

The edition.cnn.com uses HTTP/1.0 and www.google.com uses HTTP/1.1. Maybe someone can chime in on how to tell which one to use.

This works for: **www.google.com**

```
import socket
import time

domain = 'www.google.com'
# must specify index.html for google
full_url = 'http://www.google.com/index.html'


mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((domain, 80))
mysock.send('GET ' + full_url + ' HTTP/1.1\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    time.sleep(2.0)     # 2 second delay
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print data

mysock.close()
```

This works for: **edition.cnn.com**

*Warning:* Large output; consider adjusting recv(512) to a larger number or changing time.sleep(2.0) to 1 second.

```
import socket
import time

domain = 'cnn.com'
full_url = 'http://edition.cnn.com/'

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((domain, 80))
mysock.send('GET ' + full_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    time.sleep(2.0)     # 2 second delay
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print data

mysock.close()
```

Both processes finished with exit code 0